# Form to handle multiple entries (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have a form with 12 fields. This form submits the information for registering a student for courses that we offer. Currently, it only handles one registration at a time and is kind of clunky.

I want to present the user the capability to register more than one person at a time. Essentially adding multiple users' info at once before submitting the form.

I also want to have an area above the form that shows a list of people that they enter in a select, which will later be modified to have checkboxes so they may remove them, if needed.

Anyone know of any tutorials or sample showing how to do something like this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that should help you get started:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-jquery-tutorials-for-working-with-html-forms

http://designm.ag/tutorials/jquery-forms/